# Dojo NodeList.children(selector) not working when selector has a dash

Tags: dojo, css-selectors

I am trying to traverse a node list that was parsed from XML using dojox/xml/parser:

```
//required dojox/xml/parser, dojo/NodeList, dojo/NodeList-traverse, dojo/query
var doc = query(parser.parse(xml).documentNode);
```

This is working fine, however, when I attempt to traverse the children it seems I cannot select nodes with dashes in the name:

```
console.log(doc.children("someNode").length) // 1, as expected
console.log(doc.children("some-otherNode").length) // 0, should be 1
console.log(doc.children("some\-otherNode").length) // Still 0
console.log(doc.children("some\\-otherNode").length) // Still 0
```

I have tried this with css2, css3 and acme selectors requested from dojo/query. Is there some other way of escaping dashes in selectors? Or perhaps another way to traverse an xml document with dojo?

Thanks

Comment: That might be a bug. You should know that the XML parser converts the XML document to DOM nodes (it's not meant for XML documents as far as I know) and that the `dojo/query` module is meant for **real** DOM nodes. So there's a very big chance certain things might not work, nd I think this might be one of them.

Comment: OK, I will file a bug. Guess I will have to stick with XPathEvaluator for now